# Terraform code getting error, Connection failed

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, developer-tools

I created a security group in terraform , then with another TF file,I added a source of security group file. In that source file i have added one more resource '**EC2**.My terraform code intended to allocate **ec2 with SG**. but below error is comming. What could be the reason help!

**Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request send failed, Get "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connectex: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network**.

Comment: Probably an updated version of Terraform provider. But you need to add your code and Terraform version as well as the provider version.

Comment: Versions are all fine

Answer (score 1):

It could not find your AWS Credentials, which it needs to create your EC2 on AWS.  Assuming you have the AWS CLI configured, you probably just forgot to export the `AWS_PROFILE` variable into your environment, or you need to redo `aws sso login`.

When you get something back from `aws sts get-caller-identity` then you have AWS authentication sorted, and can come back to focus on getting terraform working.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, It looks like you haven't configured the AWS secrets properly. Make sure they are defined as per the [Terraform AWS documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs) and try again.